# adding an id and class to ul with jquery

Tags: jquery

How can i add a class and an id to the main ul inside a div?

```
<div id"navcont">
  <ul>
    <li>One
      <ul>
        <li>Sub One</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Two</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: That should be `<div id="navcont">`.

Comment: .addclass: http://api.jquery.com/addClass/ -- .attr: http://api.jquery.com/attr/ -- childSelector: http://api.jquery.com/child-selector/ -- Documentation exists for a reason.

Answer (score 5):

Just use a child selector:

```
$('#navcont > ul').addClass('theClass').attr('id', 'theID');
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
$('#navcont > ul').attr("id", "some-id").addClass("some-class");
```

Answer (score 4):

```
$("#navcont > ul").addClass("myClass").attr("id", "myId");
```

This will add the specified class and id to *any* ul inside the selected div, but only if that ul is a child of the #navcont div.  A ul tag inside any other tag will not be selected.  If you want to target the first selected ul tag, you could specify that:

```
$("#navcont > ul").eq(0).addClass("myClass").attr("id", "myId");
```

This will make sure you only choose the first ul inside of #navcont.  If you may have multiple ul tags inside the div, you should consider which you want to target and how to handle each.

Also remember that while a class can be used many times, and id should be unique to a document and not repeated. If you're dealing with multiple ul tags and you assign ids, each should be unique.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the first selector for this,

```
$("#navcont ul:first")
```

Note that this will select only the first UL element within the DIv